# MySQL: How to search for spelling variants? ("murrays", "murray's" etc)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search like this: the user inputs e.g. "murrays", and the search result will show both records containing "murrays" and records containing "murray's". What should I do in my query.pl?

Comment: Do you mean that when you search for "murrays", names like "murray's" will also come up?

Comment: yes right user search for "murrays", names like "murray's" will also come up

Answer (score 5):

What do you think about using the [`SOUNDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function and the [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) operator ?

That way, you can simply do:

```
SELECT * from USERS WHERE name SOUNDS LIKE 'murrays'
```

I'm pretty sure it doesn't work for every case, and perhaps it is not the most efficient way to solve the problem, but it could fit your needs.

Comment: It's definitely an option, but it will come with a computational penalty. It'll really depend on exactly what the original poster is asking to do (a single test case doesn't help us pick the "best" solution).

Answer (score 3):

This won't help if you absolutely need to do these queries in SQL, but if you can set up a [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) search index for it, you gain a lot of this kind of "fuzzy search" functionality. Note though that Lucene is quite a complex topic by itself.

Comment: Draws a lot more attention, doesn't it? Good job deciphering the original question. :D

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create an extra field in the database, which contains the data with all special characters stripped from it, and search there. A bit lame, I know. Looking forward to see smarter answers ;)

Comment: +1 for an indexable solutions - all replace(column, '\'', '') will ignore all indexes

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE REPLACE(name, '\'', '') = 'murrays'
```

Comment: This is pretty much the easiest/quickest way!

Comment: Assuming of course you are pre-processing the search string and removing the apostrophe beforehand...

Comment: It'll work, yes, but on a big data set you'll hit a bit speed penalty as you are having to pre-parse every "name" before comparison.

Comment: Thats what i meant by quick and dirty. But any solution is going to have this problem at some point. You have to remove the character to do the comparison. It's just a question of when, and how, you do it.

Comment: This is not a general answer. It works only spesific example in question.

Answer (score 2):

I would first build a search column which has the text without punctuation and then search on that. Otherwise you'll have have to have a series of regular expressions to search against or check individual records in PHP for matching: both of which are computational intensive operations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this: (untested!)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE REPLACE(user_name, '\'', '') = "murrays"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for single word searching, you could try using Soundex or Metaphone functions? These would handle sounds-like as well as spelling

Not sure if MySQL has these, but PHP does (which would require separate columns to hold these values).

Otherwise, Richy's no-punctuation extra column seems best.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a replace to your query like this

```
replace(name, '''','')
```

to temporarily get rid of the apostrophes for the match.

```
select name from nametable where name = replace(name,'''','');
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should be able to pick up "murrays" or "murray's".

```
var inputStr = "murrays";
inputStr = String.Replace("'", "\'", inputStr);
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE Replace(AField, '\'', '') = inputStr OR AField = inputStr
```

Answer (score 0):

1. strip user input and names in database from all non-letter characters.
2. Use [levenstein distance](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/) or [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) to find `murrays` with `murray` or `marrays`. This is optional but your users would love that.