# Generate string with apostrophe after each letter of original string in turn

Tags: php, string

How can I iteratively create a variant of "Murrays" that has an apostrophe after each letter? The end-result should be:

```
"m'rrays,mu'rrays,mur'rays,murr'ays,murra'ys,murray's"
```

Comment: I assume this is your homework?

Comment: It's the same user nickname, but not the same account, it seems.

Still ; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198493/mysql-how-to-search-for-spelling-variants-murrays-murrays-etc as exact duplicate

Comment: User for this question is http://stackoverflow.com/users/146970/mehul

User for yesterdays' question was http://stackoverflow.com/users/146881/mehul

Comment: @Jonathan > probably, yes ^^ but looking at the profile of this one I did not find the question -- it seemed odd, so I searched for yesterday's question, and foud it was not the same account ; only said it so that other people wouldn't have to search too :-)

Comment: I think I misread the question...

Comment: @Tom, the user deserves it after this storm. The question was confused for another, but if carefully read it is a legitimate question.

Comment: Note, I was the first to close-vote this, and now I'm saying I was wrong. I should have read it a bit more closely.

Comment: @Tom: I upvoted with absolutely no sympathy. Possibly a bit of antipathy. I clicked my mouse very sternly.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Why do you assume recursion is necessary?

Comment: @Gumbo - It was one of many options. I'm not suggesting it's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate through the name, and re-print it with apostrophe's? Try the following:

```
<?php

    $string = "murrays";

    $array  = str_split($string);
    $length = count($array);
    $output = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++) {
        $output .= $array[$j];
        if ($j == $i) 
            $output.= "'";
      }
      if ($i < ($length - 1))
        $output .= ",";
    }

    print $output;

?>
```

Comment: i want to make this type of differnt string like m'urrays,mu'rrays,mur'rays,murr'ays,murra'ys,murray's,murrays' so how to make this type of string using php pl help

Comment: Shame on you posting this outside of a comment, Sampson.

Comment: Don’t use `count` in your looping condition if the size of the array doesn’t change. Better define a variable that holds that value.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
<?php                      
function generate($str, $add, $separator = ',')
{
    $split = str_split($str);
    $total = count($split) - 1;

    $new = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
    {
        $aux = $split;
        $aux[$i+1] = "'" . $aux[$i+1];
        $new .= implode('', $aux).$separator;
    }
    return $new;
}
echo generate('murrays', "'");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another solution:

```
$str = 'murrays';
$variants = array();
$head = '';
$tail = $str;
for ($i=1, $n=strlen($str); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $head .= $tail[0];
    $tail = substr($tail, 1);
    $variants[] = $head . "'" . $tail;
}
var_dump(implode(',', $variants));
```

Answer (score 0):

well that's why functionnal programming is here

this code works on OCAML and F#, you can easily make it running on C#

```
let generate str =
     let rec gen_aux s index =
         match index with
             | String.length s -> [s]
             | _ -> let part1 = String.substr s 0 index in
                    let part2 = String.substr s index (String.length s) in
                    (part1 ^ "'" ^ part2)::gen_aux s (index + 1)
     in gen_aux str 1;;

generate "murrays";;
```

this code returns the original word as the end of the list, you can workaround that :)

Comment: sorry folks I didn't pay attention to the php tag!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$array = array_fill(0, strlen($string) - 1, $string);
implode(',', array_map(create_function('$string, $pos', 'return substr_replace($string, "\'", $pos + 1, 0);'), $array, array_keys($array)));
```